# Access keep prompting me a value on a query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've query in MS Access. It's quite obvious but Access keeps prompting me to enter the value `t1.Mois` and `t2.Mois` which I don't want to.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
SELECT t2.Mois
FROM
    OtifDataToExport AS t1 
    left JOIN 
    (
        SELECT TOP 3 avg(t3.ratioOnTime) as moy
        FROM [OtifDataToExport] as t3
        where t3.Mois < t1.Mois
    ) as t2 
    ON t1.Mois = t2.Mois
```

Comment: Thanks @lee Mac, this was the issue.

Comment: @Lee Mac, I succeeded in moving forward, now I'm stuck in a matter to reduce outcomes based on previous data. I've submitted another post "Reduce outcomes base on sub query". If you can help me, it would be great!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving the prompt because the subquery `t2` does not contain the field `Mois`, only `moy`; as such `t2.Mois` is interpreted as a parameter to be supplied during evaluation.

Therefore, you'll either need to change the subquery `t2` to output a column called `Mois`, or alternatively link on the `moy` column.

It's difficult to advise the appropriate solution without seeing data or expected results.